# why is this null value not being serialized?

Tags: java, gson, retrofit2

So I've got  an object that we are serializing to gson, the `end` value is null.  But instead of showing up as `null` in the json object the whole key value pair for `end` is just missing from the json object.

Here is the POJO for the object.

```
public static class History {
   @NonNull
   public final String areaId;
   @NonNull
   public final String userId;
   public final long start;
   @Nullable
   public final Long end;
   public History(@NonNull String areaId, @NonNull String userId, long start, @Nullable Long end) {
        this.areaId = areaId;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
   }
}
```

Here is the gson Builder

```
GsonBuilder()
    .serializeNulls()
    .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateFormatter())
    .setFieldNamingStrategy(fieldNamingStrategy)
    .create();
```

This is what the json actually looks like

```
areaUserHistories": {
         "aff824c6-df4f-49b4-8dea-6c204cb7bb16": {
         "areaId": "ca5f5e6f-77eb-4859-a2ad-c3b249e53493",
         "start": 1524178713,
         "userId": "911705136"
        }
    }
```

This is what it should look like,

```
areaUserHistories": {
         "aff824c6-df4f-49b4-8dea-6c204cb7bb16": {
         "areaId": "ca5f5e6f-77eb-4859-a2ad-c3b249e53493",
         "start": 1524178713,
         "end": null
         "userId": "911705136"
        }
    },
```

---

**EIDT 1**

So I was experimenting and I added this line of code to the GsonBuilder,  `.setLongSerializationPolicy(LongSerializationPolicy.STRING)`

so that the Gson Builder now turns Long values into a String.  This resulted in the `end=null` value being added correctly. Unfortunately the value needs to be a Long.

Comment: What key value pair? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please show us some input and output

Comment: I've edited the question the "end" variable is the one that is null.   I've added actual json and expected json.

Comment: Show the code that uses the Gson instance. I can't reprodcue this behavior in a minimum sample when using GsonBuilder.serializeNulls.

Comment: @EricCochran  the GsonModule is being used in the Retrofit library and I have been unable to find the class that actually uses the GsonModule.

Comment: I've added an edit (edit 1) based on some experimentation.

Answer (score -3):

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();

gsonBuilder.serializeNulls();

Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

String jsonString = gson.toJson(object);
```

Comment: The OP already has this exact code.  How does this answer the question?

Comment: No it isn't. Look closer

Comment: If you explain what makes this a relevant answer, he's not have to look at all.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.